# How do i avoid of installing a bunch of node modules that are not even listed in my package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

```
"dependencies": {
"jquery": "^2.2.3",
"normalize.css": "^4.1.1"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"browser-sync": "^2.12.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my `package.json` file, and when i delete folder named *node_modules* and then run *npm install*, as expected it should only install those that are in my `package.json` file but instead,  it installs a bunch of different(over 100)modules that i don't even need.

What do i need to do here?

Comment: Each module in your `package.json` has dependencies to own used modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now way to avoid that. Each module from your *package.json* file has dependencies to its own modules so that is why you are getting

> a bunch of different

ones.

See this:

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.
>   This will hopefully eliminate most cases where windows users ended up with paths that were too long for Explorer and other standard tools to deal with.